# Fixed width sidebar in Foundation 6 without collapse

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am working on a layout that fixes the size of a sidebar because our design doesn't handle squeezing on that element well, but does handle squeezing for the primary content (sidebar will have a hand full of different nav elements). I am following the advice of Miko [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/709-whats-the-recommended-way-to-setup-a-fixed-width-sidebar-with-flexible-content-in-foundation-5). I know this is for foundation 5 but the it worked nicely except for I had to add the `collapse` class to all of my rows. I still want my gutters to be maintained via foundation. I created an example layout with a bunch of different colors to test it out.

```css
.section {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .section {
    max-width: 1024px;
  }
  .section.sidebar-left {
    padding-left: 335px;
  }
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 335px;
  top: 0;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-left {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section sidebar-left story-grid">
    <div class="sidebar show-for-large sidebar-left" style="height: 100%; background-color: green;">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="row collapse" style="background-color: orange;">
        <div class="row collapse" style="height: 50px; background-color: blue;">Full Width</div>
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div style="height: 50px; max-width: 355px; background-color: pink;">Fixed Width</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="columns small-1" style="height: 50px; background-color: purple;">1 Column</div>
            <div class="columns small-1" style="height: 50px; background-color: purple;">1 Column</div>
            <div class="columns small-1" style="height: 50px; background-color: purple;">1 Column</div>
            <div class="columns small-1" style="height: 50px; background-color: purple;">1 Column</div>
            <div class="columns small-1" style="height: 50px; background-color: purple;">1 Column</div>
            <div class="columns small-1" style="height: 50px; background-color: purple;">1 Column</div>
            <div class="columns small-1" style="height: 50px; background-color: purple;">1 Column</div>
            <div class="columns small-1" style="height: 50px; background-color: purple;">1 Column</div>
            <div class="columns small-1" style="height: 50px; background-color: purple;">1 Column</div>
            <div class="columns small-1" style="height: 50px; background-color: purple;">1 Column</div>
            <div class="columns small-1" style="height: 50px; background-color: purple;">1 Column</div>
            <div class="columns small-1" style="height: 50px; background-color: purple;">1 Column</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="columns small-2" style="height: 50px; background-color: red;">2 Columns</div>
            <div class="columns small-2" style="height: 50px; background-color: red;">2 Columns</div>
            <div class="columns small-2" style="height: 50px; background-color: red;">2 Columns</div>
            <div class="columns small-2" style="height: 50px; background-color: red;">2 Columns</div>
            <div class="columns small-2" style="height: 50px; background-color: red;">2 Columns</div>
            <div class="columns small-2" style="height: 50px; background-color: red;">2 Columns</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="columns small-3" style="height: 50px; background-color: brown;">3 Columns</div>
            <div class="columns small-3" style="height: 50px; background-color: brown;">3 Columns</div>
            <div class="columns small-3" style="height: 50px; background-color: brown;">3 Columns</div>
            <div class="columns small-3" style="height: 50px; background-color: brown;">3 Columns</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="columns small-4" style="height: 50px; background-color: crimson;">4 Columns</div>
            <div class="columns small-4" style="height: 50px; background-color: crimson;">4 Columns</div>
            <div class="columns small-4" style="height: 50px; background-color: crimson;">4 Columns</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="columns small-6" style="height: 50px; background-color: darkcyan;">6 Columns</div>
            <div class="columns small-6" style="height: 50px; background-color: darkcyan;">6 Columns</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `story-grid` class does nothing except change font color and add some height for demo purposes. The result is this:

[image: layout demo]

This almost exactly what I want except -- I still want gutters. If I remove the `collapse` class it looks like this:

[image: broken layout]

I am hovering over the content section to show how the internal grid system is overflowing it parent's boundaries. So how do I get the result I got above without collapsing my gutters?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work. Remove `collapse` from everything and add this to your css `.row .row { margin: 0; }`

Foundation adds a negative margin on nested rows and it changes with screen width, but depending on exactly what you want to achieve, I think this will do it.

I also edited your post from `@media` `max-width: 600px` to `min-width: 600px`, because it didn't look like your screenshots.